# Considerations on an archive HDD

Tags: backup, hard-drive, archiving

I need to buy a hard drive to store monthly backups of my in-home lab. I need an 8 TB disk and I've been looking at Seagate's Archive HDD's. From what I'm read, these drives are designed to run in cold storage systems, because SMR cause low write speeds, and thus are not suitable for regular operation due to performance.

What worries me, is that cold storage are, theoretically, systems that are scarcely accessed, so I'm worried that making monthly backups will somehow reduce their lifespan (I haven't read in the user manual or other documentation anything about how these drives should be used any different from regular ones).

My backup plan is:

- Keep the drive unmounted
- Every month, mount the drive, delete the oldest backup and write new ones
- Unmount the drive

Considering temperature, HDD's are kept between 30-35 ºC (86-95 ºF)

Will this plan reduce the disk's lifespan? Are there any other considerations I should know about these drives?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't forget that a fire can burn any kind of hard drive. Offsite storage is essential.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that a power spike was more likely (even with the UPS and all), so reading the suggestions here I'll very likely be looking to an offsite (possibly cloud solution as suggested) for backup archiving

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Disks are highly unpredictable. Some disks could go for years, I've got ordinary desktop disks running since 2009 and their still good today. I also got this high performance disks and it just died (less than a year of work). **So if your data is highly valuable, if you must store them in your own disks, I suggest you make multiple copies on separate disks.**

2) What reduces the lifespan of the disk is if you actually are using them. Vibrations, temperatures and writes on the disks.

3) If it works for you, I strongly suggest you take cloud solutions for storing your backup. They are more efficient and **safer as far as storage is concern, avoiding the risk of disk failures.** Go for [Amazon Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/) if you will store data that you don't plan of accessing always, like Back-ups.

EDIT:

Lifespan of the disk and integrity of data in them can also degrade/decay even if the disk is not used. Factors such as bits loosing their magnetic orientation can be a problem but could be mitigated if the disk is periodically refreshed. Warm environments can likewise degrade the disk itself.

Also consider: [Google Nearline for Cold Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage-nearline/)

Comment: "What reduces the lifespan of the disk is if you actually are" - yes, THE DISC. What reduces the lifespan of the mechanism sometimes can also be NOT using them, so that it freezes into place. Bad then if the "disc" is good but you still have to pay for a clean room repair to access the data. You also blatantly overlook bit rot for non-working and non-refreshing discs.

Comment: @TomTom That is true and I will edit my answer. Data degradation can be an issue specially if the data is not refreshed by periodically rewriting it. Also. room conditions can also cause degradation to the very material the disk is made. Ultimately, I suggested Cloud solutions if you cannot spend for the infrastructure yourself. Nealine is also great.

Comment: Downloading data from Amazon Glacier can be very expensive, as it's priced according to your busiest hour for the month, multiplied by hours in the month. https://medium.com/@karppinen/how-i-ended-up-paying-150-for-a-single-60gb-download-from-amazon-glacier-6cb77b288c3e

Comment: @Tim And who cares? He talks about BACKUPS - 99% of the data will never be read, just discarded at the end of the holding period. I agree no cloud - would consider Backblaze, though.... pricing wise they are good.

Comment: I agree, it will HOPEFULLY not be read, because that'll mean something went really south

Answer (score 1):

> I need to buy a hard drive to store monthly backups of my in-home lab.

Why would anyone do that on A drive?

Any professional setup includes multiple backups ON SEPARATE MEDIA. Get that part. One month per hard disc (if you want to go the hard disc route). Bad things happen - and you do not want to loose all backups just because something bad happened.

Generally HDD are not a super good media for long term storage unless regularly activated. Bit rot will kill data over time (unless refreshed, something many file systems support - but that takes TIME to rewrite the disc and it must be active).

I would suggest going with tapes - and getting a klima system to control storage temperatures into the approoved levels.

Comment: I'll take note on having separate disks, however, I don't have hardware for tapes, as this is a rather _amateur_ setup.

Any comments about archive HDD's though?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: No, because if you read the site rules, we do not deal with amateur setups here.

Comment: The setup is amateurish, but if you pay attention to the question, it is about archive HDD's, which are used in professional environments

Comment: Archiving, though, is not backup. Archiving HDD still expect to run (like in a RAID). What they technically are are LARGE and SLOW (it is assumed a lower IO budget is enough) - but otherwise not really different.